# MySQL: Sum quantities excluding first occurrence

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have three tables for an e-commerce website.

Table `orders(id)`

Table `products(id, name)`

Table `order_products(id, order_id, product_id, quantity)`

I need to sum the total quantities for each product sold, but with one condition:

- Only if the product has been ordered more than once.

I already done this by counting the total orders for each product and putting the condition `HAVING COUNT(orders.id) > 1`

The problem I am facing is that I need to exclude the quantities of the first order when I sum the quantities for each product.

Here is my simplified query

```
SELECT
    order_products.*,
    COUNT(orders.id) tot_orders,
    SUM(order_products.quantity) tot_ordered
FROM order_products
LEFT JOIN orders ON order_products.order_id = orders.id
GROUP BY order_products.product_id
HAVING tot_orders > 1
ORDER BY tot_ordered DESC
```

This only shows products that have been ordered more than once (as in more than one order, not more than one quantity), but the sum of the quantity still takes in account the first order, which I do not want.

Is it possibile to subtract those quantities in this query ? I want to avoid doing another query while looping through this results.

Thank you

**EDIT** Here is a sample example

- Order n1:

  - product_1 qta 1
  - product_2 qta 2
  - product_3 qta 1
- Order n2:

  - product_1 qta 1
  - product_2 qta 1

The result I am expecting is this:

- product_1 qta 1
- product_2 qta 1

Basically I summed only the quantities of those products ordered more than one, excluding the first order (product_1 and product_2 has been calculated, product_3 has not been calculated because it has been ordered only one)

**EDIT2/SOLUTION** Ok, i think i figured it out. I've added a sub-query in the original query that only counts the quantities of the first order, than I subtract this values from the total quantities. This is the sub-query

```
(
    SELECT
        SUM(first_product.quantity)
    FROM order_products first_product
    LEFT JOIN orders ON first_product.order_id = orders.id
    WHERE first_product.id = order_products.id
) first_order_qta
```

The `order_products.id` is referencing the outside table, not the one inside the sub-query.

Comment: So you've got order #1 with product #A with quantity 10, order #2 + product #A +qty 5, order#3 product #A qty 2, and you don't want (10+5+2) but just want (5+2) ? First of all i can't understand why but is this really what you want ?

Comment: @PierreGranger This process is called (translated from italian) "re-order", basically checking which products have been ordered more than once for reasons outside my knowledge

Comment: provide you order_products table structure have any other field in table, or in your table have any field which we can identify first order of user ?

Comment: @MahipalPatel That is the problem, there is no field indicating if an order is the first one, that's my problem. I somehow need to get that order with its products and subtract them from the total quantities for each product. The other fields of the order table are insignificant for this problem (created_on, client_id, etc..)

Comment: check below my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45235771/5917258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this, i check in my local and it works.

```
SELECT
    order_products.*,
    COUNT(orders.id) tot_orders,
    SUM(order_products.quantity) tot_ordered - (SELECT op.quantity from order_products op WHERE op.product_id = order_products.product_id ORDER BY created_on LIMIT 0,1)
FROM order_products
LEFT JOIN orders ON order_products.order_id = orders.id
GROUP BY order_products.product_id
HAVING tot_orders > 1
ORDER BY tot_ordered DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not run your query but it seems to be the exact thing I did in my final update so it should work

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you just mixed up `tot_orders` and `tot_ordered`

```
SELECT order_products.*
         , COUNT(orders.id) tot_orders
         , SUM(order_products.quantity) tot_ordered
FROM order_products
LEFT JOIN orders ON order_products.order_id = orders.id
GROUP BY order_products.product_id
HAVING tot_ordered > 1
ORDER BY tot_ordered DESC
```

In case you want to substract the first order try:

```
SELECT order_products.*
     , COUNT(orders.id) tot_orders
     , SUM(order_products.quantity) - 1 tot_ordered
FROM order_products
LEFT JOIN orders ON order_products.order_id = orders.id
GROUP BY order_products.product_id
HAVING tot_ordered > 1
ORDER BY tot_ordered DESC
```

EDIT: I made a third query in order to subtract number of orders from total quantity:

```
SELECT OP_ID
     , OP_OID
     , OP_PID
     , tot_ordered - tot_orders AS qta
FROM (
    SELECT op.id OP_ID
         , op.order_id OP_OID
         , op.product_id OP_PID
         , COUNT(orders.id) tot_orders
         , SUM(op.quantity) tot_ordered
    FROM order_products op
    LEFT JOIN orders ON order_products.order_id = orders.id
    ) base
GROUP BY order_products.product_id
HAVING base.tot_ordered > 1
ORDER BY qta DESC
```

Comment: You are right, I tried to paste the important mysql code and I miss-typed. I will try your solution right now

Comment: Just checked your query, unfortunately it does not work because it subtracts  1 quantity from the total, but the quantity can be any number

Comment: I Edited and provided a third querry maybe thats your solution.

Comment: That does not work either. I eventually managed to do it, if you are interested check OP for updates.